# Creating a new variable in Scala case block?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

These two statements behave the same :

`def getNum(inp: String): Double = inp match { case "" | null  => 0.0 case _ => inp.toDouble }`

`def getNum(inp: String): Double = inp match { case "" | null  => 0.0 case x => x.toDouble }`

Question is, where should either one be used and is one essentially better than the other?

Comment: The second is just more readable. Though the first one will never throw an exception, but it is always risky if you add more stuff in the method in future and forget to document it.

Comment: I guess `if (inp == "" || int == null) 0.0 else inp.toDouble` is even better than your first code sample.

Comment: Both versions will throw NumberFormatException for unparseable strings.Agree with senia reg the optimization. 
Another argument could be that 2nd version may be slower due to an extra reference being created? But any other stylistic or performance considerations in choosing either one are welcome.

Comment: Senia's version is what I would use. With Scala 2.10 you can also use: `Try( inp.toDouble ).getOrElse( 0.0 )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bytecode for the two is identical, so you can use whichever you prefer stylistically.

Note that in some cases you may have a complex expression as the source of your value to match, which makes it harder to refer to.  Thus you may have greater consistency of style with the `case x => x.toDouble` form.